# URL Decoding in PHP not working as supposed to be

Tags: php, urldecode

I am trying to decode this URL string using PHP's urldecode function:

```
urldecode("%3CR201810579707%3E%20%3C20180828%3E%20%3C20180912%3E%20%3C1033.00%3E%20%3CY%3E%20%3C0.00%21NA%3E");
```

This is supposed to output...

```
<R201810579707> <20180828> <20180912> <1033.00> <Y> <0.00!NA>
```

...but instead is ouptutting this

```
<20180828> <20180912> <1033.00> <0.00!NA>
```

I've tested the string in a [php online decoder](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urldecode/) with great success, but can't seem to do this operation server side. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you outputing text with *angle brackets* into **HTML context**? (How about view source?) Or did you test this on the command line?

Comment: [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e32016890da068c5669f49eb6e76508092275c4), everything works fine

Comment: Just type `<R201810579707> <20180828> <20180912> <1033.00> <Y> <0.00!NA>` in the "Your Answer" box here. Everything that resembles a valid HTML tag will be handled as such and you'll get `<20180828> <20180912> <1033.00> <0.00!NA>` in the preview pane. That's how HTML works, it doesn't have anything to do with URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're printing the result on a web page, the angle brackets will be treated as tag delimiters. You can display it literally by calling `htmlentities()`:

```
echo htmlentities(urldecode("%3CR201810579707%3E%20%3C20180828%3E%20%3C20180912%3E%20%3C1033.00%3E%20%3CY%3E%20%3C0.00%21NA%3E"));
```